# Redirecting the home page to index.php, not index.html

Tags: uri

I have an index.html file in the server root directory.

When users browse the domain, the index.html page should come first. In that index.html, I have created a link like **enter website** that links to index.php present in the server root directory to enter the Drupal site. When I click on the **Home menu** link, it automatically redirects to index.html; I need it to redirect to index.php.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You should explain how you forced the web server to serve index.html as index file; by default, on Apache, Drupal serves index.php for http://example.com.

Comment: i have used splashify its working, but when i used option always initially its display the costume page after that its not enter into drupal site pleaes help me what to do ???

Answer (score 2):

Why use separate index files when you can use a *splash screen*:

> We define a splash page as being content that shows up at a specified interval, at a specified location, one time. If someone goes to a certain page for the first time, we want to make sure the splash content shows up. But if the person is coming from an internal link on the site, we don't want the splash content to show up over and over again (otherwise, the splash page would become a nuisance).

These modules implement the flash features in a Drupal site:

1. For D6 : https://drupal.org/project/splash
2. For D7 : https://drupal.org/project/splashify

Comment: i have used splashify its working, but when i used option always initially its display the costume page after that its not enter into drupal site pleaes help me what to do ???